# input a function, get "str" object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a command prompt style program in Python. I want to have a list of possible functions to run, and then check the list; if any of them match, take the input that matched and call a function with the same name. I currently get a `"str" object is not callable` error.

```
import os
import time

able_commands = ["clear", "test"]


def test():
    print("worked")


def run_command(command):
    command()
    input_command()


def clear():
    print("clearing...")
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system('cls')


def input_command():
    command = input(os.path.abspath(os.sep) + " ")
    check_if = command.lower()
    if check_if in able_commands:
        run_command(check_if)
    elif check_if == "":
        input_command()
    else:
        print("ERROR \nPlease specify a valid command")
        input_command()


input_command()
```

I'm a beginner with Python.

Comment: Having `input_command` recursively call itself is probably not a good idea. You are basically looking for a `while True:` loop with a `break` when you get valid input. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Pro tip: stop using `os.path`. It's api is clunky. Use the much more expressive `pathlib` which has a very nice OOP approach

Comment: Why would you print the path as the root directory as the prompt anyway? If you want to make a CLI, print the current working directory; but none of this is important to your actual question, so it should be removed from the question. See also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions are first-class objects. So, you could do something like this:

```
def foo():
    print('foo')

def bar():
    print('bar')

# Create a dict of function name to the function object. 
# This dict must be declared after your functions otherwise
# you will get a NameError exception.
funcs = {
   'run_foo': foo
   'run_bar': bar
}

# Select the function from the dict
f = funcs['run_foo']

# Run the selected function
f()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of what you require is to change your `run_command` function to the following:

```
def run_command(command):
    functionToCall = globals()[command]
    functionToCall()
    input_command()
```

There are similar questions already that answer this, however for a "newbie", it may not be clear that they in fact are the same, or how they'd fit into your implementation.

Comment: Don't encourage use of globals, even (or especially) for beginners.

Comment: @tripleee Don't confuse system global scope and custom globals, there is no crime here.

Comment: I don't think the main crime is the use of globals, but even nudging them in that direction is dubious here. At the very minimum this should include a `try:` or other guard so that `command` can robustly be any random string (but then you run into security issues).

Comment: @tripleee Agree on something like a `try/except`, and other security considerations here. There's a lot that could be done as it's accepting user input.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can call functions like this using globals() and locals(). In your case, you can replace line `command()` inside `def run_command(command)` with this:

```
globals()[command]()
```

This will find your function by name and call it. Be careful when using [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) though, and please also [read this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string). You will find more ways of calling your function and explanations there. I hope, this helps.